# How to place a custom user control inside a HierarchicalDataTemplate in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've got a custom tree view set up and I've got a UserControl from another project that I want to use as the node/nodes for my tree. This is what I currently have:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="GraphStyle.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="nodes" Source=".\nodes.xml" XPath="Node"/>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Node" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Children/Node}">
            <UserControl 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Width="200" Height="60">
                <Grid Background="Red" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,0,5,0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="38*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="125*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="37*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" TextAlignment="Left" Height="35"/>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="buttonAddQuestionNode" Grid.Column="1" Height="12" Margin="57,45,56,-22" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="12">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/BlogSample;component/Icons/addIcon.png"/>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="A" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="25" Height="35"/>
                    <Path Grid.Column="1" Data="M100,35 L100,45" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="11" Margin="62,0,62,-11" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                </Grid>
            </UserControl>

        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<TreeView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GraphStyle}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource nodes}}"/>
</Window>
```

The section under HierarchicalDataTemplate is where I'm placing my usercontrol as the node. My question is there a way to simply reference the usercontrol instead using the code like this? Or is there a better way to do this I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you should create your `UserControl.xaml` in your Project. For example, you create such UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.SomeUserControl"
             <!--The code omitted for the brevity-->
             <!--Your code of your UserControl from the MainWindow-->
     >
    <Grid Background="Red" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,0,5,0">
        <!--The code omitted for the brevity-->
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Then in your Window where `HierarchicalDataTemplate` is located you should write short name to your namespace which has your UserControl. For example, my project is called "WPFApplication1" and short name for namespve will be **"local"**:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"        
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    <!--The code omitted for the brevity-->
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
 <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="GraphStyle.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="nodes" Source=".\nodes.xml" XPath="Node"/>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="aaa">                
           <localUC:SomeUserControl/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>         
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

**Update:**
Is it okay for you?

```
<TreeView>
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <local:SomeUserControl/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ItemsSource}"/>
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.Resources>
        <TreeViewItem Header="1">
            <TreeViewItem Header="21">
                <TreeViewItem Header="31">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="41">
                        <TreeViewItem Header="51">
                            <TreeViewItem Header="61">
                                <TreeViewItem Header="71">

                                </TreeViewItem>
                            </TreeViewItem>
                        </TreeViewItem>
                    </TreeViewItem>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>

    </TreeView>
```

Comment: I set it up like that with the correct namespaces and nothing shows as wrong when I build it, but when I run it, I only get the lines that connect the nodes, not the nodes them selves. It's like the treeview doesn't see the style at all, so just it just leaves it blank. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes. I'm double checking my namespaces to make sure I'm not missing a reference somewhere.

Comment: What is this line supposed to be: <!--Your code of your UserControl from the MainWindow--> ?

Comment: I had to leave the office for the day, but I'll test it first thing Monday.